# Messaging Between Corvid Page Code and HTML Element, Getting [object Object] Instead of the Actual Message, How to Correct My Codes?

Tags: javascript, html, velo

I am trying to understand messaging between page code and HTML element using Wix's Corvid.

I have the following 2 items on page:

- A HTML element called "html4"
- A text element called "text32"

I have a code in the HTML element "code" part, which waits for the page to load, then sends a message ("Message from iFrame") to the page, then waits for an answer from the page. After getting the answer, shows the answer:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        window.parent.postMessage("Message from iFrame", "*");
        window.onmessage = (event) => {
            if (event.data) {
                document.getElementById("theLabel").innerHTML = event.data;
            }
        };
    })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <span id="theLabel" class="label">HTML Label</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

The page code waits for the first message from the HTML element, then sends an answer to it.

```
$w.onReady(function () {
 // TODO: write yor page related code here...
    $w("#html4").onMessage( (event) => {
        let receivedData = event.data;
        $w('#text32').text = receivedData;
        $w("#html4").postMessage("answer from Corvid");
    } );
});
```

On the page, the text element is above and the HTML element is below. So I am expecting to see:

-Message from iFrame

-answer from Corvid

But instead, I see this:

-Message from iFrame

-[object Object]

Then after a few seconds, "[object Object]" becomes "answer from Corvid" for a few milliseconds and becomes "[object Object]" again.

What I want to do is having the actual message properly.

Comment: you are getting back an object. an object can't be rendered in html, but it's individual properties can.... _before_  setting the `innerHtml` try adding `console.log(event.data)` and opening up your dev tool to see the object being sent back. Then rendering a single property of it. or all of it, your choice.

Comment: console shows this: {"target":"content script","data":"SYNC"}